# Plot distribution on 2D surface

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 2d

I have an array containing 3 coordinate points X.Y.Z and two variables, speed of sound and density.
This variables are extracted from CFD results. The size of the array is quite big, each coordinate and variable has a lenght of 3037493.
I would like to extract the centerplane at z=0 and plot the speed of sound distribution in python.
If I try with np.meshgrid I get a memory error, if I plot it with tri_surface I do not manage to get only the centerplane. Can you help me?
Here my code

```
xd=[]
yd=[]
zd=[]
cd=[]
rhod=[]
with open(meanflowdata,'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader=csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in spamreader:
        if len(row)>2:
            if float(row[0])<=4.80e+02:
                if float(row[0])>=1.57e+02:
                    xd.append(float(row[0]))
                    yd.append(float(row[1]))
                    zd.append(float(row[2]))
                    cd.append(float(row[3]))
                    rhod.append(float(row[4]))

Xd=np.asarray([xd,yd,zd,cd,rhod])
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"})
surf = ax.plot_trisurf(Xd.T[:,0], Xd.T[:,1], Xd.T[:,3], cmap=cm.jet, linewidth=0.1)
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
plt.show()
```

[image: I get this results, whereas I would like to have something with x,y, and the distribution plotted on x,y at z=0]

Comment: It looks like you only need to do a `np.histogram2d` on `xd,yd` and render the result with `plt.imshow`

Comment: Also, you can use `if len(row) < 2 and (157 <= float(row[0]) <= 480):`

Comment: @QuangHoang the point is that my distribution is 3D, so I have x,y,z and for example density. With the histogram I can onlzy plot the bins but I have an array. Essentially I would like to extract a slice from my 3D data and plot it.